# df.mean(axis=1) is returning only NaN values

Tags: python, append, average, nan

I'm trying to do the following: open different files ending with a certain text (C1_LRC) with a loop, append the column of interest from each file into a new dataframe. Last, I want to calculate the average from these columns. The problem is that I get NaN values instead of the average and I don't understand why. I attach an example of the output. Thank you in advance

```
path = 'C:/.../...'
dfs=[]

for file in os.listdir(path):
if file.endswith('C1_LRC.TXT'):
    with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", header=1)

        dfs.append(df)

big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1,  ignore_index=True)
big_frame['average']=big_frame.mean(axis=1)
print(big_frame)
```

[image: output example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your column datatypes with

```
print(big_frame.dtypes)
```

It looks like your columns are not `float` but `object`, since the topmost row is non-numeric. For example, the column name `"0"` has value `Area 1` on the first row. Naturally, the "average" of non-float data will always be not a number (`NaN`).

Comment: thanks @np8, you're right! but then should I convert object into float?

Comment: Yes. But in this case I think the problem is on how you read the data from the files. The column names are now read as part of the data. Check the [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation. I guess you want to change the `header` to be `2` (the second row in the file), but I cannot say for sure since haven't seen your data files.

Comment: changing the header number solved the problem, thank you!